# Invoke route from Processor

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Camel to integrate 2 systems. I have defined different routes and one of the routes consumes from a specific rabbitmq queue and send it to a REST service. Nothing fancy here, the route looks like this:

```
public class WebSurfingRabbitToRestRoute extends RouteBuilder{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("rabbitmq://rabbit_host:port/Rabbit_Exchange").
        setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST")).
        setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json")).
        bean(TransformResponse.class, "transform").
        to("http4://rest_service_host:port/MyRestService).
    }
}
```

As you can see, i process every message before sending it to the rest service since i need to adjust some things. The problem comes when i find out that sometimes (i dont know how or when), the system that publish into rabbit, send 2 messages concatenated at once.

What i expect to get is a simple json like this:

```
[{field1:value1, field2:value2}]
```

What i sometimes get is:

```
[{field1:value1, field2:value2},{field1:value3, field2:value4}]
```

So when i face this scenario, the rest service im routing the message to, fails (obviously).

In order to solve this, i would like to know if there is a way to invoke a route from inside a processor. From the previous snippet of code you can see that Im calling the transform method, so the idea will be to do something like the following pseudo-code, because after the route is already fired, i cant split the events and send them both within the same route "instance", so i thought about invoking a different route that i can call from here which will send the message2 to the very same rest service.

```
public class TransformRabbitmqResponse {
    public String transform(String body) throws Exception {
    // In here i do stuff with the message
    // Check if i got 2 messages concatenated
    // if body.contains("},{") {
    //    split_messages
    //    InvokeDifferentRoute(message2)
    //}
}
}
```

Do you guys think this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

One option (though I am not sure this is the *best* option) would be to split this up into two different routes using a `direct` endpoint.

```
public class WebSurfingRabbitToRestRoute extends RouteBuilder{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("rabbitmq://rabbit_host:port/Rabbit_Exchange")
        .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", constant("POST"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .bean(TransformResponse.class, "transform");

        from("direct:transformedResponses")
        .to("http4://rest_service_host:port/MyRestService");
    }
}
```

And then in your transform bean, you can use camel [Producer Template](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) to publish the transformed payload(s) to your new direct endpoint (assuming you are using json?).

```
producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:transformedResponses", jsonString);
```